# How can I generate a JavaScript object literal in C#?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create the following JavaScript object literal in C# code, as a string, and am looking for some tips on how to best do this.

```
model: {
    id: "Id",
    fields: {
        Surname: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
        FirstName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
        PrivateEmail: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
        DefaultPhone: { type: "string" },
        CompanyName: { type: "string" },
        CreateDate: { type: "date" },
        LastLoginDate: { type: "date" },
        IsLockedOut: { type: "boolean" }
    }
}
```

This defines a client side object with a *model* property that reflects what each row in my MVC4 view model will look like. I can use plain reflection to generate a string literal, but I would rather somehow tap into already available JSON serialization services in .NET. To do so I think I would need to create an anonymous object with properties corresponding to the JS properties above. How could I do this?

**EDIT:**
I need to loop over the properties in a view model class and generated a C# object that will serialize to a JavaScript 'transform' of the view model class similar to the one above.

Comment: Should the resulting code look like that, or is it dynamic? Can't you just put it in a literal string?

Comment: @Guffa I want to put the code in a literal string; I just don't want to roll by own serializer using just icky string concat.

Comment: Ok, I gave you the solution for a literal string. If you don't want that, what do you want?

Comment: I want to generate a JavaScript object literal inside a C# string. I think my title hints at that. That's how a lot of json serialization is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think he may be asking is to convert a C# object to a JSON string.

Try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

or

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

EDIT (an example on how to use):

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": new Date(1230422400000),
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

**EDIT:**

This is the comment from [@yyamil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293227/how-can-i-generate-a-javascript-object-literal-in-c/10293991#comment70564123_10293991):

You can also use anonymous objects in case you don't want to create a new class just to serialize a json object:

```
var notificationPayload = new
{
    notification = new
    {
        title = "Title", 
        body = "body"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationPayload);
```

Comment: Thank you Mathew, i was hoping my question wasn't quite as obtuse as @Guffa would suggest, but I'm also asking how to dynamically get those properties into the C# object so they get properly serialized.

Comment: I need to create a dynamic object, with one Field property for each property e.g. in Product. This part my question doesn't make clear enough, but you have answered the part that is clear correctly.

Comment: @ProfK what I do remember that there was a project on CodeProject that allowed you to take a JSON result and create all the related object including the serialization/deserialzation aspects (using the NewtonKing Json.NET library)

Comment: Great answer. You can also use anonymous objects in case you don't want to create a new class just to serialize a json object:  var notificationPayload = new { notification = new { title = "Title", body = "body" } };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notificationPayload);